# Why Union results same value in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, union

having 3 variable in Union , on even changing these value , Union variable print value as change in last one

unable to paste a code:

The problem is:

When after defining 3 variable in union 
initialising their value
m1=1
m2=2

output: 
m1 =2
m2=2
result printing the same value for the each union variable

Comment: Your question is not clear. It might help if you show your code.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use a struct rather than a union. A union is just a single variable, but one where there are multiple choices of valid value.

A struct, of the other hand, is a single variable with many values within.